# How to return a promise when writestream finishes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, fs

I have such a function, which create a write stream and then write the string array into the file. I want to make it return a Promise once the writing is finished. But I don't know how I can make this work.

```
function writeToFile(filePath: string, arr: string[]): Promise<boolean> {
   const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
   arr.forEach(function(row) {
     file.write(row + "\n");
   });
   file.end();
   file.on("finish", ()=>{ /*do something to return a promise but I don't know how*/});
}
```

Thank you for any comment!

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function writeToFile(filePath: string, arr: string[]): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    for (const row of arr) {
      file.write(row + "\n");
    }
    file.end();
    file.on("finish", () => { resolve(true); }); // not sure why you want to pass a boolean
    file.on("error", reject); // don't forget this!
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right. I don't need to pass a boolean. void shall be enough.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you're returning a boolean (or void) then do you really need a promise?

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla you're returning a *promise for* a boolean. So you still know when the operation succeeds, or whether it doesn't.

Comment: Oh, I see. so the use case for this would be something like:

    writeToFile('foo').then(function(response) {
        console.log(response); // true
    }

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla yes, exactly

Comment: Hi Bergi, I just had a follow up question. Isn't writableStream.write() asynchronous? If yes, how can we know when all the `file.write(row)` statements have been executed?

Comment: @Lubor Afaik, it's done when it emits the `finish` event.

Comment: @Bergi But in this code we use `file.end()` to emit `finish` event, right?

Comment: @Lubor Do we? I don't think so, `.end()` has to be asynchronous as well to work. But maybe you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), in this answer I've just converted your original code to promise style without knowing many details about write streams.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I think so. I tried to put break points to the line of `resolve()` after removing `file.end()`, and I can see the the program 'never' hit this line. I guess no finish event is emitted.

Comment: The documentation of `Writable.write()` says that: `If false is returned, further attempts to write data to the stream should stop until the 'drain' event is emitted.` but your (and OP's) code doesn't handle it.

Comment: @umitu IIRC it's still "safe" but inefficient - if you keep writing, the stream buffer will just keep growing (potentially until running out of memory). But it's not my code, I just copied that bit over from the OP's question. Indeed, I would not recommend writing it like that.

Comment: This answer is being discussed on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422349/is-it-abuse-to-answer-then-dupe-hammer-a-question

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the `Promise` before the operation was done.
Something like:

```
function writeToFile(filePath: string, arr: string[]): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
        arr.forEach(function(row) {
            file.write(row + "\n");
        });
        file.end();
        file.on("finish", () => { resolve(true) });
    });
}
```

Comment: `reject` is there for...