# How to upload a file into Firebase Storage from a callable https cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload a file to **Firebase storage** using a callable firebase cloud function.
All i am doing is fetching an image from an URL using `axios` and trying to upload to storage. 
The problem i am facing is, I don't know how to save the response from axios and upload it to storage.

First , how to save the received file in the temp directory that `os.tmpdir()` creates.
Then how to upload it into storage.
Here i am receiving the data as `arraybuffer` and then converting it to Blob and trying to upload it.
Here is my code. I have been missing a major part i think.
If there is a better way, please recommend me. Ive been looking through a lot of documentation, and landed up with no clear solution. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

```js
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const {
        imageFiles,
        companyPIN,
        projectId
      } = data;
      const filename = imageFiles[0].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
      const filePath = `ProjectPlans/${companyPIN}/${projectId}/images/${filename}`; // Path i am trying to upload in FIrebase storage
      const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
      const metadata = {
        contentType: 'application/image'
      };
      axios
        .get(imageFiles[0], { // URL for the image
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
          headers: {
            accept: 'application/image'
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          const blobObj = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: 'application/image'
          });
          return blobObj;
        })
        .then(async blobObj => {
          return bucket.upload(blobObj, {
            destination: tempFilePath    // Here i am wrong.. How to set the path of downloaded blob file
          });
        }).then(buffer => {
          resolve({ result: 'success' });
        })
        .catch(ex => {
          console.error(ex);
        });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // unknown: 500 Internal Server Error
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unknown error occurred. Contact the administrator.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd take a slightly different approach and avoid using the local filesystem at all, since its just tmpfs and will cost you memory that your function is using anyway to hold the buffer/blob, so its simpler to just avoid it and write directly from that buffer to GCS using the `save` [method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save) on the GCS file object.

Here's an example.  I've simplified out a lot of your setup, and I am using an http function instead of a callable.  Likewise, I'm using a public stackoverflow image and not your original urls.  In any case, you should be able to use this template to modify back to what you need (e.g. change the prototype and remove the http response and replace it with the return value you need):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.doIt = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    const IMAGE_URL = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg';
    const MIME_TYPE = 'image/svg+xml';
    return axios.get(IMAGE_URL, { // URL for the image
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
          accept: MIME_TYPE
        }
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);  // only to show we got the data for debugging
        const destinationFile = bucket.file('my-stackoverflow-logo.svg');  
        return destinationFile.save(response.data).then(() => {  // note: defaults to resumable upload
          return destinationFile.setMetadata({ contentType: MIME_TYPE });
        });
      }).then(() => { response.send('ok'); })
      .catch((err) => { console.log(err); })
  });
```

As a commenter noted, in the above example the axios request itself makes an external network access, and you will need to be on the Blaze or Flame plan for that.  However, that alone doesn't appear to be your current problem.

Likewise, this also defaults to using a resumable upload, which [the documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save) does not recommend when you are doing large numbers of small (<10MB files) as there is some overhead.

---

You asked how this might be used to download multiple files.  Here is one approach.  First, lets assume you have a function that returns a promise that downloads a single file given its filename (I've abridged this from the above but its basically identical except for the change of `INPUT_URL` to `filename` -- note that it does not return a final result such as `response.send()`, and there's sort of an implicit assumption all the files are the same `MIME_TYPE`):

```js
function downloadOneFile(filename) {
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  const MIME_TYPE = 'image/svg+xml';
  return axios.get(filename, ...)
    .then(response => {
       const destinationFile = ...
     });
}
```

Then, you just need to iteratively build a promise chain from the list of files.  Lets say they are in `imageUrls`.  Once built, return the entire chain:

```js
let finalPromise = Promise.resolve();
imageUrls.forEach((item) => { finalPromise = finalPromise.then(() => downloadOneFile(item)); });

// if needed, add a final .then() section for the actual function result

return finalPromise.catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
```

Note that you could also build an array of the promises and pass them to `Promise.all()` -- that would likely be faster as you would get some parallelism, but I wouldn't recommend that unless you are very sure all of the data will fit inside the memory of your function at once.  Even with this approach, you need to make sure the downloads can all complete within your function's timeout.

Comment: Don't forget that the project needs to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" pricing plan. As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes, thank you.  I've extended the answer to note that as well.

Comment: Loading it all into memory like this isn't really any different than loading it into /tmp.  They are all both the same memory, billed the same, and in both cases, the file occupies the same amount of memory after the request complete.  If you really want to avoid memory usage like this, pipe a stream from an HTTP request directly to a write stream to GCS.

Comment: Exactly. No reason to write to the filesystem since it's more complex code and costs the same as just buffering in memory. I also suspect that for small files even streaming will have a similar buffer, but using `responseType: 'stream'` and connecting it to a stream for the file is a good approach (though it would also involve [some complexity to fit into the promise model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880832/how-to-return-a-promise-when-writestream-finishes) which wasn't quite germane to this question).

Comment: For multiple files, how can we adapt this function?

Comment: @devil-0-per I have added one possible approach to do that.